# Evidence from Sunnah or Quran that tawhid is divided into 3

Tags: tawheed

Is there any proof from the sunnah or Qur'an that tawhid should be categorised into 3 parts. I've seen many scholars particularly of the Ashari creed opposing this while a few scholars such as Al Tabari, Ibn Taymiyya, Ibn Al Qayyim and later Muhammad Ibn Abd Al Wahhab saying that tawhid is divided into 3 categories:

Tawheed al-Ruboobiyyah (Oneness of Divine Lordship), Tawheed al-Uloohiyyah (Oneness of Divinity) and Tawheed al-Asma’ wa’l-Sifaat (Oneness of the Divine Names and Attributes). Which one is the correct view (if possible to answer)?

Comment: Division of tawheed into any specific categories is a scholarly convention. It has no bearing on any real beliefs. The actual question and debate is not about categorization but about whether worshiping Allah alone is a part of tawheed regardless of how you categorize it.

Answer (score 4):

This is indeed the correct and complete view of Tawhid in Islam. And this categorization can be found in the greatest and very first Surah in the Quran, **Al-Fatiha**. Where Tawheed al-Asma’ wa’l-Sifaat is found in the 3rd verse (The Most Beneficent, the Most Merciful). Tawheed al-Ruboobiyyah is found in the 4th verse (The Only Owner [and the Only Ruling Judge] of the Day of Recompense [i.e. the Day of Resurrection]). And finally, Tawheed al-Uloohiyyah is found in the 5th verse (You [Alone] we worship, and you [Alone] we ask for help [for each and everything]).

Where in general, the verses that talk about the Actions and Might of Allah are categorized as Tawheed al-Ruboobiyyah. Where as the verses that talk about directing the act of worship solely to Allah are categorized as Tawheed al-Uloohiyyah. While the verses that talk about Allah's Names and His Attributes are categorized as Tawheed al-Asma’ wa’l-Sifaat.

This categorization encompasses the entire Quran and can be found all over.